# Jenkins Bitbucket with PuTTY cache

Tags: jenkins

In Jenkins, in the console output, it shows the message

```
The server's host key is not cached in the registry....
If you trust this host, enter 'y' to add the key to the PuTTY's cache and carry on connecting
```

The problem is I cannot enter yes or no on the console output. So after some research, it said to enter in the script something like

```
echo y | script name
```

When I tried that, the message still shows and hangs on it. After aborting the job, then it echos' yes. Is there another way enter y when the putty cache message is displayed.

Comment: Are your jenkins in linux or windows?  Is just a proof of concept?

Comment: I'm using it on windows server 2008

Comment: Windows is not the best choice to host Jenkins. Anyway, how are you trying to clone git repository in jenkins : plugin or shell invocation?

Comment: Yea, I know Windows is not the best choice, but they don't provide Linux to us. When I cloned the git repo, on Jenkins windows batch command, I entered the the command to clone it

Comment: Are you using ssh or https git url repository?

Comment: ssh git url repo

Comment: So we set up the keys in plink, and in cmd, it works fine because I can enter yes, but I am not sure how I can do that with Jenkins

Comment: Could you try to create a key without passphrase in order to avoid the key enter requirement? Just try it and after that we can discuss about security issues.

Comment: I don't think a passphrase was created with the key. I will double check if it was, I'll remove it

Comment: uhmmm sounds rare. The steps to clone a git url with ssh are : (1) generate a key pair (public and private) and register in your git provider. (2) start some process which load your private key, ready to exchange a validation with your remote git provider (plink in windows and ssh-agent in linux) . (3) Clone your repository using a ssh url. At this point the process previously started, validate your private key with public key registered in your git provider. (4) Clone ends with success